# Struggling with MongoDB grouping by year, month and day query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

DB STRUCTURE

```
date: 2022-01-01T03:28:00.000+00:00 (Date)
value: XXX (int)
```

write a queries to group documents by year, month and day summing relative values

```
filter_cond = {"$match": {"dt": {"$gte": datetime.fromisoformat(dt_from), "$lte": datetime.fromisoformat(dt_upto)}}}

if group_type == 'year' or group_type == 'month':
    group_cond = {"$group": {"_id": {"period": {f"${group_type}": "$dt"}}, "total_value": {"$sum": 1}}}
elif group_type == 'day':
    group_cond = {"$group": {"_id": {f"${group_type}OfMonth": "$dt"}, "total_value": {"$sum": "$value"}}}

sort_cond = {"$sort": {"_id": 1}}

pipeline = coll.aggregate([filter_cond, group_cond, sort_cond])
```

output format

ex:

```
month: 2022-11-01T00:00:00
total: XXX
```

using: pymongo

Comment: Using some [Date Expression Operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/aggregation-quick-reference/#date-expression-operators) and a `"$group"` stage should help you get the output you want.

Comment: @ray that was helpful, but I'm still struggling to get the correct output. I need to get date in "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" format but get only a number of the month instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$dateTrunc` with `unit: "day"` in `$group`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$date",
          unit: "day"
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "$sum": "$value"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Uu6o_KMVIlD)